# gaps between objects in box2d

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm having trouble with box2D. As you can see in the screenshot below, there are gaps between all the objects. (everything you see drawn is a box2d object). I'd really like to fix this but I don't know what to do. I've tried messing with the meters2pixels and pixels2meters constants:

```
static constexpr float M2P=10; // meters to pixels
static constexpr float P2M=1/M2P; //
```

it works alright when M2P is 10, but then the problem is that 1 meter is much too small on the screen. i would like to set it at 60, ideally, which is what it is in the screenshot below.

[image]

anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Float?  I suspect the screen width (and height) is a fixed integer number of pixels.  Thus the gaps might be explained by (poor choices of) the arithmetic for computing the object's display position.

Comment: how many pixels a meter is, determines how big a 1 meter box will be on the screen. the problem is that if i want a big meter, there are gaps, so if i set a small meter, well, not only is it small, but it takes forever to fall, and does so slowly. i must be doing something wrong. sorry im just thinking out loud, it's hard to debug graphical issues sometimes.

Comment: Please provide more code that relates to the picture shown. In the meantime, I'd guess that these gaps are due to the "skins" that Box2D uses and that your seeing them is due to your squares being too small relative to the size of the skin. See [Box2D b2_common.h](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/master/include/box2d/b2_common.h#L74) for some more details on this "skin".

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full code and being able to compile it myself, it is hard to figure out exactly what is causing your issue; however, I think a good step in the right direction is to review [this](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/blob/master/testbed/tests/pyramid.cpp) code from the Box2D GitHub. It provides a clear example that appears similar to what you are trying to do. I would be able to help you more if you post your code.

Answer (score 0):

" Box2D generally works best when objects are the size of typical real world objects. For example, a barrel is about 1 meter tall. Due to the limitations of floating point arithmetic, using Box2D to model the movement of glaciers or dust particles is not a good idea."

https://box2d.org/documentation/md__d_1__git_hub_box2d_docs_hello.html

Probably you are running into the limits of precision and getting rounding errors. 60 meters per pixels would mean that your square objects above, occupying around 20 pixels, are over 1km in world size!!!